# POST file to REST API without saving it to disk

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get a file from an url, and then post it to an REST API without writing it to disk.

I get this error: ValueError: cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples

Would I need to convert the downloaded file somehow?

```
import requests
import json

image = requests.get("https://mandekogebogen.dk/image/box/2128376/1960/50000.jpg")

url = "https://api.dinero.dk/v1/56780/files"

payload={}
files={'file':image.content}
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: I think it wants a filename for the file you're sending. Can you try `files={'file':('filename.jpg', image.content)}` ? See also: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: Thanks. Now I get not supported media type.